# Vimeo API: Pause Event responding only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, froogaloop

Using the following code. The problem is that the pause event is only being fired at the beginning for some reason and when I actually pause the video through the video control buttons within the iframe, it's not responding. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers!

```
// ------------------------------------------
// initialiaze video's
// ------------------------------------------

var readyness = new Array;

$( 'iframe.video-api' ).each( function() {

    var playerID = this,
        playerIDname = $( playerID ).attr('id');

    var playerFrame = $( '#' + playerIDname )[0];

    $f( playerFrame ).addEvent( 'ready', videoReady );

});

function videoReady( playerID ) {

    if ( $( '#' + playerID ).hasClass( 'video-single' ) ) {

        $f( playerID ).addEvent( 'pause', videoPauseSingle );

    }

    clearInterval( readyness[playerID] );

}

function videoPauseSingle( playerID ) {

    $( '#btn-single-video' ).fadeIn( 400 );

}

// ------------------------------------------
// control single video
// ------------------------------------------

$('#btn-single-video .video-button').click( function() {

    var playerID = $( this ).data('video-id');

    $f( playerID ).api('play');

    $( '#btn-single-video' ).fadeOut( 600 );

});
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPKeyM?editors=001

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, thanks for your reply. Found the problem. Apparently on my localhost it's not working when embedding http video link. Changed it to https and it all worked out.